# Uploading or sending a file with class data in json to WebAPI 2 in RESTful to WebAPI2 does not work

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to upload a file with some associated data from a C# win app to a WebAPI 2.0 using HTTP POST, but the request does not seems to be created corectly, however when I try to send them seperately it works fine.

Below is Win App Code for Upload:

```
public bool Upload(string url, string filePath, string localFilename, string uploadFileName)
{
    Boolean isFileUploaded = false;

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var fileStream = File.Open(localFilename, FileMode.Open);
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(localFilename);

    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Headers.Add("filePath", filePath);
    content.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), "\"file\"", string.Format("\"{0}\"", uploadFileName + fileInfo.Extension));
    TestDocument td = new TestDocument();
    td.Field1 = "ABC";
    td.Field2 = "PQR";
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(td);
    var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data");
    content.Add(httpContent);
    var result = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    return true;
}
```

At Api end:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Testdocument document)
{
    HttpResponseMessage result = null;
    Testdocument otd = new Testdocument();
    otd = document;
    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
    if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        var docfiles = new List<string>();
        foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
        {
            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
            var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + postedFile.FileName);

            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            docfiles.Add(filePath);
        }
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, docfiles);
    }
    else
    {
        result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: So what is the problem? Is there an error?

Comment: @tomredfern It does not connect with Api, however if I remove the below:" var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data");
        content.Add(httpContent);" it works fine. Basically it does not work.

Comment: So there's an error?

Comment: Yes. in winform HTTPRequest code.

Comment: And what does that error say?

Comment: @tomredfern there are no such error shown, `httpClient.PostAsync(url, content)` nothing gets sent to webapi.